# Change / Filter dropdown list based based on ownership

Tags: django, django-forms

This has got to be a common requirement but nothing I've found on SO or in Django docs that works for me. I'm really new to Django. My problem: I need to change the list of Areas that are presented in a form dropdown list according to the company that has Area ownership.

In my app:
Accounts (i.e Users) are members of Company. A Company manages an Area. Within the Area are a number of Routes. Routes can be added/updated/removed or assigned to different Areas by the Company.

So on my forms I want to make sure that only Areas that belong to a Company are displayed in the dropdown list. Essentially a user would select an Area, then CRUD routes associated with the Area.

```
class Company(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(...
     account_number = models.CharField(...
     ...


class Account(models.Model):
    name = models.OneToOneField(User...
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    ...

class Area(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    number = modes.PositiveIntegerField(...

class Route(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area)
```

In forms.py

```
class RouteCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model= Route
        fields= [
            'area',
            'route_number',
            ...
        ]
```

Adding:

```
     self.fields['area'].queryset = Area.objects.filter(owner_id = 2)
```

provides the correct filtering but of course is not dynamic.

I've a lot of variations on :

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ??how to pass in user to ultimately get to owner_id??
    self.fields['area'].queryset = Area.objects.filter(owner_id = owner_id)
```

but can't get the middle right. I've also tried passing in 'user' but the only results in a TypeError at /account/setup/route/create
**init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using generic CreateView, you can modify your form per request by overriding get_form() on your view. That would look like this:

```
class RouteCreateView(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = RouteCreateForm

    def get_form(self):
       form = super(RouteCreateView, self).get_form()
       form.fields['area'].queryset = Area.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)
       return form
```